# Propriedades de Navegação - Domain-Driven Design

Tags: java, c#, orientação-a-objetos, ddd

Olá,

Estou estudando DDD e me deparei com a seguinte questão:

Existe o Agregado (***Aggregate***), um conjunto de objetos relacionados e que possuem uma Raiz de Agregação (***Aggregate Root***). Até então tudo bem, criei uma rotina que gerasse todas as informações partindo do Agregado Raiz e armazenando no Banco de Dados.

Preciso recuperar as informações desse agregado, vi que no livro azul de Eric Evans deu a entender que para recuperar o Agregado é necessário incluir todas as informações relacionadas a ele.

No meu cenário o Agregado Raiz possui associações com três entidades, mas queria recuperar a informação de apenas uma dessas entidades, acredito que buscar o Agregado de maneira completa acabaria afetando a performance, pois resultaria em dados que não utilizaria. Não sei se isto é correto ou se eu compreendi errado.

**Dúvida:** é válido retornar apenas uma informação de dentro desse agregado sem precisar buscar o Agregado por completo (com todas as informações) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No meu cenário o Agregado Raiz possui associações com três entidades, mas queria recuperar a informação de apenas uma dessas entidades, acredito que buscar o Agregado de maneira completa acabaria afetando a performance, pois resultaria em dados que não utilizaria. Não sei se isto é correto ou se eu compreendi errado.

Um AGREGADO é um grupo de objetos associados que tratamos como sendo uma unidade para fins de **alterações de dados**.

> Dúvida: é válido retornar apenas uma informação de dentro desse agregado sem precisar buscar o Agregado por completo (com todas as informações) ?

Sim, você pode criar uma consulta com apenas os dados desejados, desde que o controle do acesso aos objetos dentro do limite da sua agregação seja feito pela entidade RAIZ do agregado.

Pontos de atenção:

- Objetos externos devem fazer referências somente a raiz da agregação
- Não permita edição de dados da agregação que não passem pela raiz